# Typescript - Get a prototype with defined values for different classes

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So I want to create a function that takes a class and creates a prototype for it. But in this prototype, every property of the class is defined (including the optional ones). So here's what I want:

```
class Bar {
    public i?: number
    //...
}

class Foo {
    public a?: string;
    public b?: number;
    public c?: Array<string>;
    public l?: boolean;
    public d?: Bar;

    //...
}

const prot = getPrototype<Foo>();

console.log(prot); //My expected output: { a: "", b: 0, c: [], l: false, d: {}, ... }

const prot2 = getPrototype<Bar>();

console.log(prot2); // My expected output: {i: 0, ...}
```

I really can't see any way of doing this. If you think there's a way, I'd love to see one. The values given to the properties are supposedly hard-coded values for each type. Something like this:

```
//...
//... the logic for the getPrototype function ...
//...
    if(typeof property === "string"){ prototype[property] = ""; }
    else if(typeof property === "number"){ prototype[property] = 0; }
    //...
//...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by making use of Mapped Types and Conditional Property by creating a type alias `InitializeType<T>` and make use of it for defining the type of `getPrototype<T>`

```js
class Bar {
    public i?: number
    //...
}

class Foo {
    public a?: string;
    public b?: number;
    public c?: Array<string>;
    public l?: boolean;
    public d?: Bar;

    //...
}

type InitializeType<T> = {} & { 
  [K in keyof T]-?: 
    string extends T[K] 
      ? ""
      : number extends T[K]
      ? 0
      : boolean extends T[K]      
      ? false
      : Array<any> extends T[K]
      ? []
      : object extends T[K]
      ? {}
      : T[K]
    }


declare function getPrototype<T>(): InitializeType<T>

const prot = getPrototype<Foo>();


console.log(prot); // output: { a: "", b: 0, c: [], l: false, d: {}, ... }

const prot2 = getPrototype<Bar>();

console.log(prot2); // output: {i: 0, ...}
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYCdoG8CwAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDTED8AXNAHZ4C2BApghttAPScB0fGAXwwZQkGADEA9pJTts%20IqWhhq0CABcExWgHMA3HKwKSZAqvpNWBzPMInowVQEEECMAE8APBq26AfNYcxkogqgTSIMxgtIG2imQAJqrwCNaGXLz86ELoGOruOMzQAJK0xOrEYCQAXswAKgXMnnV%200AC8KALQAGQo0HIA2gDS5LTQANbM7pIAZtB1ALoAtKrpPto60MwAHurMtAkwdcML-TYcFNAARFfpWDQWLEg7ewdHJ3fQlwAMnzThkki0S2u32h3mJw4WE%20lxmVQgzD%200Bcbi80XcrReYPeQwWMOgAzx52wNEkBAAVsxgOoQa9wcdcfjkDkodAaAyiRwcsJ0AkqeAEEUZnhaNTiJIxjpmOoAAoISTqBWNZp%20AAUAEoaKVypUavVlS0ecAJRpcPKaR0pbLzUrCp4pJI1errNwOAA9Cg8kQmwHMHggSQ6VU4c3OjIAWXcIMK1OYCWgkjw6nw6hoyGUNBuABpoAQaN8c8AaIScyAaHCQAicwk0wIc3weNBuehjbRTSGFQAmdrQK1yhW2popJ0uzjuz25Fs%20yL%20wPB82dsOuyPRql7eOJ5NJtPEfP1vgCIA)

getPrototype implementation:

You'll need to define the initial value of these fields in classes and just pass that object to getPrototype()

```js
function getPrototype<T>(t: T): InitializeType<T> {
  return t as InitializeType<T>
}

getPrototype(new Foo());
```

[Code Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mp9d6W)

Comment: Thank you for the clever solution, upvoted that. But as kind of a beginner, may I ask how I should implement the getPrototype function's body for it to work?

Comment: Sure, I'll share that implementation with you by tonight, it will be exactly similar to the one we did in `InitializeType`, till then you can upvote and accept the answer thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I will surely accept the answer as soon as that happens, and I'm pretty sure I already upvoted your answer. Thanks for the generous help

Comment: @dev-mirzabicer There is no way you can implement the body of this function without something like `reflect-metadata` and even then what if the types are objects types, not primitives?

Comment: @dev-mirzabicer you'll need to define the initial value of these fields in classes and just pass that object to `getPrototype()` 
[Implemenation](https://tsplay.dev/mp9d6W)